# How can I list a string in .txt to .csv format using Python?

Tags: python

Here inside of my.txt file are bunch of strings:

```
Setting Process Priority to NORMAL: Success 1

Successfully setting POL Flag to 0
VSGetVirusPatternInformation is invoked
Reading virus pattern from lpt$vpn.527 (2018/09/25) (1452700)



LPT$VPN Pattern Version : 1452700

Successfully setting POL Flag to 0
Scanning partition sector of disk C:VSGetDiskData() not defined.

Scanning boot sector of disk C:VSGetDiskData() not defined.




Scanning samples_extracted\07831df482f1a34310fc4f5a092c333eeaff4380-> 
(MS Office 1-0)->Found Virus [TROJ_CVE201711882.UHAOBHAO]
```

I'm trying to trim those sha1 and description then put it in a .csv file like this here in output:

[image: This is a sample output csv]

How can I get those string using if(after "\" and before "->") then place it in csv, it's very hard and I can't think of an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

INPUTFILE = 'input.txt'
OUTPUTFILE = 'output.csv'
PREFIX = '\\'
DELIMITER = '->'

def read_text_file(inputfile):
    data = []
    with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if not line == '':
            line = line.split(PREFIX, 1)[-1]
            parts = line.split(DELIMITER)
            data.append(parts)

    return data

def write_csv_file(data, outputfile):
    with open(outputfile, 'wb') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                                quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in data:
            csvwriter.writerow(row)

def main():
    data = read_text_file(INPUTFILE)
    write_csv_file(data, OUTPUTFILE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This worked man, but it doesn't list the sha1 to csv. here is the output to me:Found Virus [TROJ_CVE201711882.UHAOBHAO]
(Microsoft RTF 6008-0)

Comment: Is your input file different from the input example you listed? I was able to test this with the example input you provided and it worked fine for me. Here is what the output CSV file looks like on my end: 

"38d8244b00bb9662581bd6ef9562850accc907d0","(ASCII text 18-0)"
"3bff2501c649f8ee8cb69d2601a43958b7f59644","(Microsoft RTF 6008-0)"

Also note I just edited my answer and changed it so it will strip off everything up to and including the backslash (\\) in the string instead of working off a fixed prefix value

Comment: also the Found Virus [TROJ_CVE201711882.UHAOBHAO] it trims the first parts but the second part didn't

Comment: it still outputs the whole content of the txt but it does put the sha1 to the columns

Comment: I didn't see "Found Virus [TROJ_CVE201711882.UHAOBHAO]" in your example input file. I see you updated your question. I'll get back to you with an updated answer shortly

Comment: Can you upload a more thorough example input file to pastebin? What you pasted in your question seems to have been messed up in formatting. There's a newline between "Scanning samples_extracted\07831df482f1a34310fc4f5a092c333eeaff4380-> " and "(MS Office 1-0)->Found Virus [TROJ_CVE201711882.UHAOBHAO]"

Comment: This file appears to be dseigned for human consumption and is full of variable formatting that will make parsing it into a machine readable format very difficult. I can try to come up with something, but it's likely you'll need to pre-process the file to remove non-machine readable content. Is there any way you can configure the software that is generating this file to produce a file in a more machine readable format? It also looks like you're trying to collect the SHA1 signatures of these files - you can probably compute these signatures directly in python instead of an external program